# How to convert Map[A, B] into a key-value string sorted by String?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a Map:

```
val m = Map("foo" -> 10, "bar" -> 5)
```

I want to convert this into a String in the following format (keys and values are separated by ":", different elements are separated by ","):

```
"bar:5,foo:10"
```

Note that the keys are now ordered.

How do I write a function to perform this conversion generically? I tried

```
def f[A, B](m: Map[A, B]): String = {
  m.toList.sortBy(_._1).map { x => x._1 + ":" + x._2 }.mkString(",")
}
```

But this doesn't work, because somehow I need to specify that `A` is orderable. I'm not sure how to do this -- I tried adding an implicit `Orderer` parameter to my function, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `Ordering` typeclass:

```
def f[A: Ordering, B](m: Map[A, B]): String = {
  m.toList.sortBy(_._1).map { x => x._1 + ":" + x._2 }.mkString(",")
}
```

This adds another parameter list to `f` with an implicit `Ordering` parameter. The method signature is actually translated to this behind the scene:

```
def f[A, B](m: Map[A, B])(implicit evidence: Ordering[A]): String
```

The `evidence` parameter is then picked up by `sortBy` and used for comparing elements.

EDIT:

Note that you cannot use `Ordered` in the same way as `Ordering`. The `Ordered` trait is meant to be mixed in with the very object type that will be sorted (like in Java). In other words, `A` would have to extend `Ordered[A]` and then you would write it as `A <: Ordered[A]`.

However, this inheritance approach with `Ordered` is less powerful than the typeclass approach with `Ordering`, because it is less flexible. If somebody else defined `A` and didn't decide to make it extend `Ordered[A]`, then you wouldn't be able to use it with `sortBy` (at least not without creating a wrapper class). On the other hand, you can always declare a new implicit `Ordering[A]` in scope without changing what `A` inherits, and implement this `Ordering` in any way you like. This allows you both to define how the objects of type `A` are ordered when the implementer of `A` has forgotten to do so, and to redefine how they are ordered when you want a non-default ordering.

Comment: Thanks! One thing I still don't understand, though: could you explain why `f[A: Ordered, B]...` doesn't work?